# after-make-frame-functions does nothing for an otherwise working function

Tags: init-file, server, daemon, workgroups

I am using [workgroups](https://github.com/tlh/workgroups.el) and I have the following code in my `init.el`:

```el
 (defun my-start-emacs (_)
   (interactive)
   (message "HI")
   (sleep-for 1)
   (if (daemonp)
       (progn
         (if (not (boundp 'server-wg))
             (progn
               (wg-create-workgroup "server")
               (setq server-wg (wg-current-workgroup)))
           (progn
             (setq current-wg (condition-case nil
                                  (wg-current-workgroup)
                                (error nil)))
             (if (not current-wg)
                 (wg-switch-to-workgroup server-wg)
               (if (not (eq current-wg server-wg))
                   (wg-switch-to-workgroup server-wg))))))))

 (add-to-list 'after-make-frame-functions #'my-start-emacs)
```

The `my-start-emacs` function creates the "server" workgroup if it does not exist, and loads it if it does. Using it manually via `M-x my-start-emacs` works perfectly, however for some reason even though it is called when I start the `emacsclient -t` (attach to server after `emacs --daemon`), nothing happens (i.e. the server workgroup is created, but is not changed to)... Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That FRAME argument to `after-make-frame-functions` that you're explicitly ignoring? Don't ignore it.

```el
(defun my-start-emacs (frame)
  "Switch client frames of an emacs daemon to the 'server' workgroup."
  (interactive)
  (with-selected-frame frame
    (when (daemonp)
      (if (not (boundp 'server-wg))
          (progn
            (wg-create-workgroup "server")
            (setq server-wg (wg-current-workgroup)))
        (setq current-wg (condition-case nil
                             (wg-current-workgroup)
                           (error nil)))
        (if (not current-wg)
            (wg-switch-to-workgroup server-wg)
          (if (not (eq current-wg server-wg))
              (wg-switch-to-workgroup server-wg)))))))
```

Comment: Perfect, it works now!

Comment: Actually... even though this method manages to restore the window layout - the buffers are not being assigned to the windows... do you know why?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I don't actually use the workgroups library, so I'd need to dig through the code/documentation to figure that one out.